# How to hyphenate Russian text with dvilualatex?

Tags: luatex

I'm failing to hyphenate Russian text with LuaTeX in DVI mode (dvilualatex).
Please, don't tell me to use `fontspec` I need a DVI file.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1251]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\fontfamily{DejaVuSansCondensed-TLF}\selectfont

\vbox{\hsize=10pt
эпидемиологических
эпидемиологических
}
\end{document}
```

dvilualatex output:

[image]

latex output:

[image]

There is something wrong with input re-encoding (`luainputenc`). I understand that **luatex** reads utf8 input and `luainputenc` tries to split input characters to single bytes. This some how breaks hyphenation. 
Maybe someone could explain what is happening and how it could be solved?

Comment: As far as I know you can use `fontspec` in DVI mode. What's the reason for using LuaTeX here is not for access to system fonts, _etc._?

Comment: luatex needed for other tricks and I need DVI file with Postcript fonts.

Comment: @JosephWright: I don't think that lualatex can use type1 fonts through fontspec. And a driver (dvips) would not be able to use open type fonts (and a probably neither a type1 font loaded by fontspec). Besides this I think this simply can't work. The hyphenation patterns used by lualatex are utf8 orientated, I don't think that they will work with an T2A encoded font. Imho dvilualatex makes sense only with more or less ascii output.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I realise the font business gets tricky: just trying to get a feel for what the underlying requirements are here. (There is a reason DVI mode is not really made obvious with LuaTeX.)

Comment: That means, patterns need to be read in cp1251 encoding as all document? I did it and indeed two hyphens appeared in that word. But still not the same as in ``latex``. Any more hints?

Comment: You need also pattern adjusted to your font encoding. Hyphenation is not done at the input -- after all the input can be manipulated a lot -- but much later, and it depends on the font encoding: during hyphenation lualatex needs to know if "charXcharY" means "ab" or "12". Look at loadhyph-ru.tex: For T2A you need the ruhyphen.tex and not hyph-ru.tex. Btw: I would at least use an utf8 encoded tex-file and \usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc} to avoid the additional hassle with the input encoding.

Comment: I tried to re-encode file in UTF8 and use ``\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}`` but with no luck.  ruhyphen.tex loads other files, how I should tell luatex to load these patterns?

Comment: With \usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc} I'm getting the same result as with cp1251 (text with some hyphens) but only if ``hyph-ru.pat.txt`` is encoded in cp1251. If its in UTF8, no hyphens at all :(

Comment: Sure. As I said: the main problem is on the pattern side, luainputenc and a 8bit encoding only makes it even more difficutl. You will have to create a language which loads the patterns for T2A, and for this you probably will have to track down all the patterns and convert them to utf8. Imho you should better describe why you think that you need dvi and T2A-encoding perhaps they are other solutions which don't needs such deep changes.

Comment: Companies document printing workflow is TEX->DVI->PS->PDF so I can't change it easily to TEX->PDF.

Comment: And for what do you need luatex? Can you externalize this part of the process?

Comment: Node traversing (adding some special nodes for tagged pdf) and other stuff.

Comment: Well I don't think that you can externalize node traversing. So you will either have to get the company to accept the tex->pdf workflow or get lualatex to use T2A-patterns.