# XeLaTeX + kpfonts + Greek

Tags: xetex, kpfonts

Because of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115627/how-do-i-use-kpfonts-with-fontspec), I'm using the following code to typeset my XeLaTeX document. The problem is, there does not seem to be any support for Greek. The Greek text in the following comes out as question marks:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[oldstylenums]{kpfonts}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\begin{document}

Some nice Greek text in the middle of an English document: μυϱίᾳ εἰμὶ διὰ τὴν τοῦ ϑεοῦ λατϱείαν.

\end{document}
```

I looked into [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24728/xelatex-with-polyglossia-and-greek), too, and hence tried to add the line

```
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}
```

to the preamble, but it changed nothing.

Comment: `kpfonts` have no support for Greek.

Comment: Can you give more information about your document? Is its main language Greek, or you have just small parts in Greek?

Comment: Only small parts are Greek, the main language is in fact Danish.

Comment: But I tried changing to Linux Libertine O completely, and it worked. Guess I'll manage with that.

Comment: Don't use T1 as text encoding with xelatex.

Comment: In case of using `kpfonts` T1 encoding is the right choice.

Comment: @TimS. But T1 is not the right choice as main encoding for xelatex (or lualatex). Hyphenation will not work correctly (see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186875/how-to-hyphenate-russian-text-with-dvilualatex) and you would have to add definitions for every non-ascii input char as you did for greek. As kpfonts can't be used with the EU1/EU2-encoding of the fontspec package then -- as egreg put it -- it is out of  question to use them in xelatex as the main font unless the text is pure ascii.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use the `kpfonts` for text, then XeLaTeX is out of the question: they don't have support for OpenType or TrueType and so they aren't suitable for usage with XeLaTeX (although some dirty tricks *might* work).

Here's a version for `pdflatex` with `babel`, where for Greek I use GFS Artemisia that's not so distant from the Kpfonts.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,danish]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{kpfonts} % for math
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{artemisia}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

København er Danmarks hovedstad og er med \num{1246611} indbyggere (2014) 
landets største byområde omfattende 18 kommuner eller dele heraf. Centrum
for byområdet udgøres af Københavns Kommune, der inkl. enklaven
Frederiksberg Kommune tæller \num{661464} indbyggere (2013) og er Danmarks 
mest folkerige kommune. I hele byregionen, den \SI{2778}{km^2} store 
Hovedstadsregionen, bor \num{1950430} mennesker (2013), der også
sammenfalder med Københavns lokaltrafikområde. Den danske hovedstad er
desuden centrum for Øresundsregionen, som er Nordens største metropolregion. 
\[
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}
\]
\textgreek{μυρίᾳ εἰμὶ διὰ τὴν τοῦ θεοῦ λατρείαν}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

For XeLaTeX, probably the best match is Palatino or a clone thereof (TeX Gyre Pagella, here) again with GFS Artemisia for Greek.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmainlanguage{danish}
\setotherlanguage{greek}
\newfontfamily{\greekfont}{GFS Artemisia}

\begin{document}

København er Danmarks hovedstad og er med \num{1246611} indbyggere (2014) 
landets største byområde omfattende 18 kommuner eller dele heraf. Centrum
for byområdet udgøres af Københavns Kommune, der inkl. enklaven
Frederiksberg Kommune tæller \num{661464} indbyggere (2013) og er Danmarks 
mest folkerige kommune. I hele byregionen, den \SI{2778}{km^2} store 
Hovedstadsregionen, bor \num{1950430} mennesker (2013), der også
sammenfalder med Københavns lokaltrafikområde. Den danske hovedstad er
desuden centrum for Øresundsregionen, som er Nordens største metropolregion. 
\[
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}
\]
\textgreek{μυρίᾳ εἰμὶ διὰ τὴν τοῦ θεοῦ λατρείαν}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here if you want to use greek from another font. Your selection `Linux Libertine O` has all glyphs mentioned.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant=polytonic]{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[oldstylenums]{kpfonts}
\newfontfamily{\greekfont}[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

Some nice Greek text in the middle of an English document: \textgreek{μυϱίᾳ εἰμὶ διὰ   τὴν τοῦ ϑεοῦ λατϱείαν}. Yes in the middle.

\end{document}
```

[image: Example using LinLibertineO greek]

*Note:* If you don't want to always type `\textgreek` you could define every symbol like in the code below e.g.: `\newunicodechar{α}{\textgreek{α}}`

If you say: well I only use the standard greek symbols, no special, you can use the few shipped with `kpfonts`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[oldstylenums]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{α}{$\alphaup$}
\newunicodechar{β}{$\betaup$}
\newunicodechar{γ}{$\gammaup$}
\newunicodechar{δ}{$\deltaup$}
\newunicodechar{ε}{$\varepsilonup$} %\epsilonup your choice
\newunicodechar{ζ}{$\zetaup$}
\newunicodechar{η}{$\etaup$}
\newunicodechar{ϑ}{$\thetaup$}
\newunicodechar{ι}{$\iotaup$}
\newunicodechar{κ}{$\kappaup$}
\newunicodechar{λ}{$\lambdaup$}
\newunicodechar{μ}{$\muup$}
\newunicodechar{ν}{$\nuup$}
\newunicodechar{ξ}{$\xiup$}
\newunicodechar{ℴ}{o}
\newunicodechar{π}{$\piup$}
\newunicodechar{ν}{$\rhoup$}
\newunicodechar{σ}{$\sigmaup$}
\newunicodechar{τ}{$\tauup$}
\newunicodechar{φ}{$\varphiup$} %\phiup your choice
\newunicodechar{χ}{$\chiup$}
\newunicodechar{ψ}{$\psiup$}
\newunicodechar{ω}{$\omegaup$}
\newunicodechar{τ}{$\tauup$}

\begin{document}
Some nice reduced Greek text in the middle of an English document: αβγδεζη...
\end{document}
```

[image: Example using kpfonts own upright greek]