# Using kepler fonts with XeLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, kpfonts

I was happily using the `kpfonts` package for my thesis, then I wanted to switch to `xelatex` for some reasons and I realized I didn't know how to use Kepler fonts with `xelatex`. The `kpfonts` package, when used with `xelatex`, silently fails, apart from the usual missing fonts substitution warnings.

```
%!TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{kpfonts}

\begin{document}

Hello World

\end{document}
```

Note that I use the `kpfonts` package specifically for its light variant, so using another Palatino-like font won't work for me unless there is a way to get a similar light version.

Any way to get it work with `xelatex`?

Comment: Possible related here? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191981/xelatex-kpfonts-greek

Comment: You're missing the most important piece of information: why do you need XeLaTeX? And no, KPfonts are by no means a variant of Palatino.

Comment: It's to be able to use Helvetica Neue as a sans serif font for titles. But I don't think that's really relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\begin{document}

    Hello World

\end{document}
```

uses Kepler-fonts

Comment: when compiled with `xelatex` as well?

Comment: Your question was "Using kepler fonts with XeLaTeX?"  ... ;-)

Comment: Yes, thank you. It seems to work, but the link posted on a comment seems to imply that `kpfonts` is incompatible with `xelatex`, so am I going to face some problem?

Comment: It is _not_ an unicode font, some _special_ characters are not available.