# Ligatures gets printed with the wrong thickness

Tags: printing, ligatures

I am writing my masters thesis project in LaTeX and is enjoying it so far. However, when printing some of the pages for review, I noticed that ligatures seems to be printed with the wrong weight and appear bold.

[image: The 'ffi' ligatures gets printed badly]

The offending ligatures looks completely normal on screen. This is not something I have experienced before with LaTeX, so if anyone have some suggestions as to what may remedy this issue, I would be very grateful. I am using `xelatex` and these packages:

```
# the following might be relevant
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[light]{kpfonts}
```

I have checked, and the fonts seems to be encoded in the PDF file. I can't say if this is a LaTeX issue or a printer issue; I hope it's not considered off topic.

Comment: Could you try on another printer?

Comment: Hehe, yes I plan to try that next time I am at the university.

Comment: Your preamble is  wrong for xelatex. You shouldn't switch to T1 and you shouldn't use the kpfonts.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer how am I supposed to load kpfonts then? If I remove either, my file does compile properly.

Comment: Okay, this is what @UlrikeFischer is referring to:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191981/xelatex-kpfonts-greek

Comment: Yes, egreg's suggestion with TeX Gyre Pagella sounds good. But I wouldn't use polyglossia but babel.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I still find it weird that everything works with xelatex, T1 and kpfonts on screen, but not in print....

Comment: It works on my printer. And regarding the "everything works": Type "Grüße" in your document and see what happens ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you for your time and suggestions.

Comment: This is probably a function of your PDF browser or print driver (if you have a PDF print driver).